# How to open CSV, PDF download links in new tab in Ruby on Rails ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How to open specific CSV and PDF download links in ActiveAdmin in new tab/window. The download links are on the index page. The gem used for creating PDF is Wicked PDF. The filters for the page should be working in CSV and PDF as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide target as blank

link_to "example", asset_path("assets/documents/example.pdf"), target: "_blank"